# Image uploading to server from gallery returning size zero in response

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

Upload.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
import static com.example.arunmannuru.arun.MainActivity.MY_PREFS_NAME;



public class Upload {

    private int serverResponseCode;

    public String upLoad2Server(String fileName, Context context) {

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        try {

            URL uri = new URL(Utilities.URL + "upload/");

            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();

            http.setRequestMethod("POST");

            http.setRequestProperty("X-apikey", Utilities.API_KEY);

            http.setRequestProperty("X-secret", Utilities.SECRET_KEY);

            http.setRequestProperty("X-filename", fileName);

            DataOutputStream doss = new DataOutputStream(http.getOutputStream());

            serverResponseCode = http.getResponseCode();

            Log.i("ResponseCode", String.valueOf(http.getResponseCode()));


            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    rd.close();
                } catch (IOException ioex) {

                }
                Log.i("Uiid=",sb.toString());


                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

                Log.d("Code:",parentObject.getString("code"));
                Log.d("Status:",parentObject.getString("status"));
                Log.d("Message:",parentObject.getString("message"));
                Log.d("Data",parentObject.getString("data"));

                JSONObject dataObject = parentObject.getJSONObject("data");
                String nameValue = dataObject.getString("uuid");

                Log.d("uuid",nameValue);


                    return nameValue;
            } else {
                Log.i("Resp", "Doesn't 200");
                return "Could not upload";
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Profile.java

```
   import camera.CameraPhoto;
        import camera.GalleryPhoto;
        import camera.ImageLoader;


        public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView ivCamera,iv_settings_pic;
            public static final String IMAGE_TYPE = "image/*";
            private static final int SELECT_SINGLE_PICTURE = 101;
            EditText firstname,lastname;
            TextView btnSignOut;
            TextView btnDeleteAccount;
            TextView btnFaq;
            TextView btnPrivacyPolicy;
            TextView btnTermsOfService;
            EditText et_FirstName;
            EditText et_LastName;
            EditText et_Email;
            EditText et_ZipCode;
            EditText et_password;
            EditText et_newpassword;
            EditText et_retypepassword;
            private WebView webView;
            TextView btnSave;

            private String userChoosenTask;

            int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;
            int SELECT_FILE = 1;
            String encoded = "";
            ProgressDialog pd;
            Bitmap bitmap;


            String filePath = "";
            CameraPhoto cameraPhoto ;
            GalleryPhoto galleryPhoto;
            String selectedImage = "";
            String uiid;



            Context context;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_adapter);
                cameraPhoto = new CameraPhoto(getApplicationContext());
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                galleryPhoto = new GalleryPhoto(getApplicationContext());
                ivCamera= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_camera);
                iv_settings_pic= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_pic_profile);
                Log.e("ProfilePic:",iv_settings_pic.toString());
                firstname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_firstname);
                lastname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_lastname);
                btnSignOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnSignOut);
                btnDeleteAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteAccount);
                this.webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
                btnFaq = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.btnFaq);
                btnFaq.setOnClickListener(this);
                btnPrivacyPolicy =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnPrivacyPolicy);
                btnPrivacyPolicy.setOnClickListener(this);
                btnTermsOfService = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnTermsOfService);
                btnTermsOfService.setOnClickListener(this);
                et_FirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_FirstName);
                et_FirstName.setOnClickListener(this);
                et_LastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_LastName);
                et_LastName.setOnClickListener(this);
                et_Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_Email);
                et_Email.setOnClickListener(this);
                et_ZipCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_ZipCode);
                et_ZipCode.setOnClickListener(this);
                et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
                et_password.setOnClickListener(this);
                et_newpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_newpassword);
                et_newpassword.setOnClickListener(this);
                et_retypepassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_retypepassword);
                et_retypepassword.setOnClickListener(this);
                btnSave = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
                btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);

                context =this;



                SharedPreferences prefs3 =getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                final String str = prefs3.getString("Set-Cookie", "");

                prefs3.getString("firstName","");
                prefs3.getString("lastName","");
                prefs3.getString("shortName","");
                prefs3.getString("email","");
                prefs3.getString("zipcode","");


                et_FirstName.setText( prefs3.getString("firstName",""));
                et_LastName.setText(prefs3.getString("lastName",""));
                et_Email.setText(prefs3.getString("email",""));
                et_ZipCode.setText(prefs3.getString("zipcode",""));



                TextView btnSignOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnSignOut);
                btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);

                TextView btnDeleteAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteAccount);
                btnDeleteAccount.setOnClickListener(this);

                TextView btnFeedback = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnFeedback);
                btnFeedback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        userFeedback();
                    }
                });

                TextView btnContactUs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnContactUs);
                btnContactUs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        contactUs();
                    }
                });



                ivCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        selectImage();
                    }
                });

            }
            private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

                galleryPhoto.setPhotoUri(data.getData());
                String photoPath = galleryPhoto.getPath();

                Log.d("PhotoPath:",photoPath);
                Log.d("Data", selectedImage);

                Upload upload=new Upload();
                uiid = upload.upLoad2Server(photoPath,context);

            }

            private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {

                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

                File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                iv_settings_pic.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }



            private void galleryIntent() {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(galleryPhoto.openGalleryIntent(), SELECT_FILE);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
            }



            private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);

                    } else {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        Intent in = cameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent();
                        startActivityForResult(in, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                        cameraPhoto.addToGallery();
                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    switch (requestCode) {
                        //Location
                         //Camera
                        case 11:
                            try {
                                Intent in = cameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent();
                                startActivityForResult(in, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                                cameraPhoto.addToGallery();
                            }catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            break;

                    }

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            private void cameraIntent() {

                try {
                    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                        askForPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, 11);
                    }else
                    {
                        try {
                            Intent in = cameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent();
                            startActivityForResult(in, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                            cameraPhoto.addToGallery();
                        }catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }


                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }


            private void selectImage() {
                final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                        "Cancel"};
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Settings.this);
                builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                        boolean result = com.example.arunmannuru.arun.Utility.checkPermission(Settings.this);

                        if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                            userChoosenTask = "Take Photo";
                            if (result)
                                cameraIntent();

                        } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                            userChoosenTask = "Choose from Library";
                            if (result)
                                galleryIntent();

                        } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }





            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                    if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)

                        onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);

                    else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)

                        onCaptureImageResult(data);
                }
            }

            public void UpdateProfile(View view) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.btnSignOut: {
                        logOUt();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btnDeleteAccount:{
                        deleteAccount();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btnBackArrow:{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this,Profile.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btnFaq:{
                       Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this,FaqActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btnPrivacyPolicy:{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this,PrivacyPolicyActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btnTermsOfService:{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this,TermsServices.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btnSave:{
                        String firstName = et_FirstName.getText().toString().trim();
                        String lastName = et_LastName.getText().toString().trim();
                        String email = et_Email.getText().toString().trim();
                        String zipCode = et_ZipCode.getText().toString().trim();
                        String password = et_password.getText().toString().trim();
                        String newPassword = et_newpassword.getText().toString().trim();
                        String retype = et_retypepassword.getText().toString().trim();
                        updateUserProfile(firstName,lastName,email,zipCode,password,newPassword,retype);
                        break;
                    }
            }

            }

            private void updateUserProfile(final String firstName,final String lastName,final String email,final String zipCode,final String password,final String newPassword,final String retype) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                String string = "update_user_profile/";

                try {
                    jsonObject.put("apikey", Utilities.API_KEY);
                    jsonObject.put("secret", Utilities.SECRET_KEY);
                    jsonObject.put("avatar", "male");
                    jsonObject.put("avatar_uuid",uiid);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                CookieManager cmrCookieMan = new CookieManager(new PersistentCookieStore(context), CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
                CookieHandler.setDefault(cmrCookieMan);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this,Profile.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(Settings.this);
                backgroundTask.execute(jsonObject.toString(), String.valueOf(cmrCookieMan), Utilities.URL+string, "update_user_profile");
            }
        }
```

It was allowing me to select image from gallery but when I upload it server it was returning successful response with image size=0. The response was like this.If we see the response it was giving response with successful response code but the image size was zero.And also when I am trying to use take photo option app starts crashing.I am using ivCamera,iv_settings_pic Imageview to hold the picture after selecting image but it was not even holding image.

Response:

```
05-19 13:35:52.940 11044-11044/com.example.arunmannuru.arun I/Uiid=: {"code":200,"status":"ok","message":"File uploaded.","data":{"uuid":"97d68cab-a9c9-48fa-890d-02e43ac265e3","type":"media"},"meta":{"size":0,"contentType":"image/png","type":"media"}}
```

Comment: I do not see code for uploading anything. `upLoad2Server()` sets a header and does nothing else. Also, `galleryPhoto.getPath()` is useless, since the scheme of that `Uri` is `content`, most likely. What book did you read that showed you this way of using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`?

Comment: I am not an expert in android.. I copied code from some website references.. Actually for that api call(upload2sercer) it just need the existing file path in device and it will returns uiid. I was bit confused.Can you please help me with this issue.@CommonsWare

Comment: "it just need the existing file path in device" -- there is no "existing file path" for content that you retrieve via `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. If you want a file, integrate [a file-picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35).

Comment: I am testing this on emulator. Do you think is it an issue??Some times it shows virtual content right.@CommonsWare

Comment: "Do you think is it an issue?" -- no.

Comment: So insted of that "ACTION_GET_CONTENT" you suggest me to choose one of the file-picker libraries right?? And what do you think about take photo issue it was crashing app once if I opt that@CommonsWare

Comment: Yes, because you want a file. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is for the user to pick a piece of content. That content does not have to be a file, let alone one that you can access. The `Uri` that you get back from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` usually will have a `content` scheme, not a `file` scheme. You are welcome to make a *copy* of that content as a file, if you wish. Using a file-picker library saves you from making that copy of the content, but it limits the user to picking actual files, not things from Google Drive, Dropbox, etc. the way `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` can.

Comment: Here is my problem.. I am getting the existing file name/file path.I have to return the file containing data as well to the server.@CommonsWare